# How to migrate to metadataV14

Tags: metadata

I have a live network working on Substrate V3 and MetadataV12. How can I migrate to the MetadataV14?

The MetadataV14 is a part of the Substrate V4. Unfortunately Substrate V4 isn't released.

Comment: Any of the polkadot-v0.*.* substrate branches represent production quality substrate releases. You can use https://github.com/bkchr/diener tool to point to a particular version of substrate.

Answer (score 5):

To migrate your chain to the V14 metadata system, follow these steps (from this [upgrade guide](https://gist.github.com/ascjones/0d81a4c44e84cacd9f714cd34a6de823)):

1. Remove any `#[pallet::metadata(..)]` attributes from your pallet's Event definition.
2. Add `scale-info` as a dependency to your pallet and runtime crates:

- `scale-info = { version = "1.0.0", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }`
- `std = [ "scale-info/std" ]`

3. Derive `scale_info::TypeInfo` for any types which derive `Decode`, `Encode`(*). For example:

```
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo)]
struct HeartbeatStatus<BlockNumber> {
    pub session_index: SessionIndex,
    pub sent_at: BlockNumber,
}
```

4. Update any pallet Call variant constructors to use named structs (previously unnamed tuple structs).
5. Update the metadata runtime API call:

```
impl sp_api::Metadata<Block> for Runtime {
    fn metadata() -> OpaqueMetadata {
        OpaqueMetadata::new(Runtime::metadata().into())
    }
}
```

(*) If the type is in a separate crate to the pallet, add the scale-info dependency as above.